# Jquery Masonry with dynamic width and height item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

Hello I have a grid on my blog (on item click i add some class  that resize the item ) but the masonry dont resize and the items are messed up.

Here is an working example: http://nemaworkshop.com/The-Smith

```
$('#featured-page').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.dbnMWLI '
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resizing the element(s), just call `$('#featured-page').masonry('reload')`.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the accepted answer didn't work for me. I was getting this error:

```
no such method 'reload' for masonry instance
```

But the following code worked for me:

```
$('#featured-page').masonry();
```